Amplifying current for PWM load
My load requires a PWM wave input with at least 5 mA and 5-15 V but my controller can only provide up to 2 mA.
My first thought was to use two NPN transistors like this. I used two so that the PWM input was not inverted.

But the voltage and current provided to my load would depend on the resistance of my load.
I have also thought about using a buffer op amp or transistor. The problem with an op amp would probably the slew rate and I do not have access to any.

I am guessing the transistor buffer would have to be set up like above, but again would not the resistance of the load impact the voltage and current delivered?
I think I am missing something conceptually important because I do not think it should be this hard to design something like this.

Do you want to deliver a fixed 5 mA current to your load, and let the load set the voltage (typical of a  LED load), or do you want to deliver a fixed voltage (you appear to be using 10 V in your simulations), and let the load draw the current it likes, up to 5 mA (typical for most other types of load) ? Note that you cannot set both voltage and current.

I need at least 5v (5-15) and 5mA

So you need a 15 V output with a fixed current limit of 5 mA maximum? This would result in 5 V at 1 kohm load, 10 V at 2 kohm load and 15 V at 3 kohm load.

I do not know what the resistance of the load is. The load is a device that is controlled by PWM.  Also I need 5mA minimum, sorry for being unclear.

You can use a two transistor buffer so the output is sink and also supplied with transitors (not sinking with resistor like your second schematic).
The Vcc should be the same or little higher than Vsig otherwise the upper transistor will saturate and make slow falling output edge.
There is no need a base resistors.


if I only had 10v could I add base resistors to make sure that the transistors work?

What is your Vsig amplitude and what Vcc do you have available?

This simple BJT circuit will work in the low kHz range and can deliver up to 100 mA, however there is no overload protection.
At higher frequencies the values of R3 and R4 need to be lower.
The input accepts typical MCU output levels.
There is no active pull down at the output, so it cannot be used to drive capacitive loads like MOSFET gates.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
